# Likelihood for a Gaussian Process with no data

Tags: likelihood, gaussian-process

[A paper that I am reading](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/iMGPE.pdf) mentions the likelihood for a squared-exponential-kernel Gaussian Process **with no data**. In particular, when the kernel function is:

$$
F(x_i, x_{i'}) = v_0\exp\Big(-\frac{(x_i - x_{i'})^2}{2l^2}\Big) + v_1\delta(i, i')
$$

then the likelihood *is a Gaussian* with zero mean and variance $v_0 + v_1$, where $v_0$ is the amplitude and $v_1$ is the white noise variance.

I'm curious as to how this is derived. How would one calculate the probability that a data point belongs to a particular Gaussian Process, if it has no data?

Answer (score 2):

Before we collect any data, the prior distribution in a GP is Gaussian with mean 0 and covariance $F(x_i, x_{i'})$, to follow your notation.

For any single point, its variance under the prior is simply $v_0 + v_1$.

For more detail, you can look at Chapter 2 of Rasmussen's [Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf).

Comment: I see, I understand why the variance under the prior is $v_0 + v_1$. However, why are we using the variance under the prior as the value for the likelihood? In particular, why the variance?

Comment: You're using the variance under the prior because you haven't collected any data yet!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's a misconception on my part: we are not using $v_0 + v_1$ as the expression of the likelihood. The actual expression for the likelihood is the Gaussian pdf $N(0, v_0 + v_1)$!